# I got myself an irritating Javascript virus

Tags: windows-7, virus, javascript

so I got a javascipt virus in my Laptop:

```
effects:
  *can't open regedit.exe and resource monitor, they just show for maybe 0.5 
   seconds and exit(they just blink), the same thing happens when I try to 
   install Anti-Virus Programs, I tried to download AVAST and AVG but they just 
   blink, and about malwarebytes, when I try to open it it doesn't show anything 
   but sometimes a window appears and gives me two options either to look online 
   for solution(which doesn't help me at all) and to exit the program.
```

please take a look at the pics.
Here, in the first picture is the task manager, the one with the "Microsoft Windows Based Script Host" are the javascript executables(in the next picture):

[image]

in the PIC2 is the file location of the said virus I suspect in the task manager(with a hidden attribute of course):

[image]

and I tried to right click>>edit on the "gcfaucx.js" file on pic2 and I think I met the source code but unfortunately it's too many words and I don't know if it's legit to post it here,
and if you have any question please do ask, I'll need it,

Answer (score 2):

Reboot the machine into safemode (NOT with networking, but the steps are the same) (https://support.eset.com/kb2268/?locale=en_US.

1. Delete the files shown in your second picture
2. Start > Run > regedit
3. Navigate to HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
4. Delete any of the keys there that associate with the files in your second image.
5. Find another machine, download Malware Bytes - Antimalware and burn to a CD.
6. Reboot your PC, with the network cable out, or the wireless disabled.
7. Once logged in, use the CD to install Malware bytes.
8. run a full scan with malware bytes, and then when asked reboot the PC. This time, reconnect the wireless or network cable.
9. Log in again, run Malwarebytes. Ensure it updates, and then run another full scan.

This should be enough to clear out most Malware. You should also run a third party virus scanner such as  Trend Micro - Housecall.